# How to make a JavaScript canvas element move with your mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas

I already know how to use jQuery to make a heading move, and I can also draw things on a JavaScript canvas. I'm now wondering how to combine these two principles to make a bee that I've drawn move with my mouse? I've tried my version on Sublime Text 3 (I'm using Windows 7 Professional Hardware and Software, so I get an error message when I try to download Sublime Text 4, by the way). Here's my version in `JavaScript/HTML/CSS`:

```js
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x = 100;
    var y = 100;
    var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        if (fillCircle) {
            ctx.fill();
        } else {
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    };

    var drawBee = function (x, y) {
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
    ctx.fillStyle = "Gold";
    circle(x, y, 8, true);
    circle(x, y, 8, false);
    circle(x - 5, y - 11, 5, false);
    circle(x + 5, y - 11, 5, false);
};
drawBee();
var update = $("html").mousemove(function (event) {
    $(drawBee()).offset({
        left: event.pageX,
        top: event.pageY
    });
});

setInterval(function () {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        drawBee(x, y);
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    }, 30);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
```

Please give me a new code to add into the `<script>` tags (used to add in JavaScript into the HTML document), and tell me my mistake, for future reference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change offset of the canvas, not bee

Answer (score 0):

If you need to move inside the canvas following the mouse position, use `$("#canvas").mousemove()` and `clientX`/`clientY` coordinates (relative to the canvas)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x = 100;
    var y = 100;
    var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        if (fillCircle) {
            ctx.fill();
        } else {
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    };

    var drawBee = function (x, y) {
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
    ctx.fillStyle = "Gold";
    circle(x, y, 8, true);
    circle(x, y, 8, false);
    circle(x - 5, y - 11, 5, false);
    circle(x + 5, y - 11, 5, false);
};
drawBee();
var update = $("#canvas").mousemove(function (event) {
    x=event.clientX;
    y=event.clientY;
});

setInterval(function () {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        drawBee(x, y);
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    }, 30);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use a global mouse object to store the coordinates. This allows me to easily plug in the mouse coordinate wherever I need them.

Also if you want the object centered on the mouse you'll need to account for the canvas x and y coordinates when updating your mouse position. As you see I subtract them from event.clientX and .clientY

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var mouse = {x: null, y: null};

var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};

var drawBee = function () {
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "Black";
  ctx.fillStyle = "Gold";
  circle(mouse.x, mouse.y, 8, true);
  circle(mouse.x, mouse.y, 8, false);
  circle(mouse.x - 5, mouse.y - 11, 5, false);
  circle(mouse.x + 5, mouse.y - 11, 5, false);
};
drawBee();

$("#canvas").mousemove(function (event) {
  mouse.x = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().x;
  mouse.y = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().y;
});

setInterval(function () {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        drawBee();
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    }, 30);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
```